# Why OEMEndDoc( SURFOBJ *pso, FLONG fl ) method is not calling from Windows 10 Photos when printing?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am developing a printer driver for Windows 10. I am using [this](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/print/OEM%20Printer%20Customization%20Plug-in%20Samples/C%2B%2B/oemps)  example to creating driver . In ddihook.cpp the [OEMEndDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/printoem/nf-printoem-oemenddoc) function is to be called by the GDI when it has finished sending a document to the driver for rendering

```
BOOL APIENTRY OEMEndDoc(SURFOBJ  *pso,FLONG fl)
{
    PDEVOBJ     pdevobj;
    POEMPDEV    poempdev;

    VERBOSE("OEMEndDoc() entry.\r\n");

    pdevobj = (PDEVOBJ)pso->dhpdev;
    poempdev = (POEMPDEV)pdevobj->pdevOEM;

    //
    // turn around to call PS
    //

    
    BOOL bRet=(((PFN_DrvEndDoc)(poempdev->pfnPS[UD_DrvEndDoc])) (
            pso,
            fl));           
    SendMessageToEventHandler("PS_CREATED_EX"); // My custom function to send the message to my application
    return bRet;

}
```

When we try to print from Windows 10 Photos (Default windows 10 photo viewer), this OEMEndDoc function is not receiving any call so that my custom method inside this api is also not working.

Interesting thing is that this problem is only for  Windows 10 Photos, When we print from other applications like MS-Paint, pdf, notepad etc this method receives the call and every thing is working fine.

May I know is this a bug related to Windows 10 Photos?

Comment: Maybe because some apps use PrintDlg and some apps use the [XPS Print](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/printdocs/xpsprint-api?redirectedfrom=MSDN) ?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis But windows 10 photos is calling some other functions in this dll like IOemPS::GetInfo, (intrface.cpp->line:152) , OEMEscape (ddihook.cpp-> lineno. 423) etc.